# ui-router nested route controller isn't being called

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to call a controller which should be linked with the `home.category`  route but it isn't being called. What's wrong in it?

```
$stateProvider    
  .state("home", {
    // Use a url of "/" to set a states as the "index".
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: APP_CONFIG.baseUrl +
      'partials/layouts/home.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .state("home.category", {
    // Use a url of "/" to set a states as the "index".
    url: "c/:categoryId/:categorySlug",
    controller: function($stateParams) {
      alert($stateParams.categoryId);
    }
  })
```

Comment: Any JS errors or is there any working fiddle?

Comment: No error, just saw that parent controller works but child controller does nothing, when I tried resolve in child so it was displaying alerts... maybe child controllers doesn't work in ui-router

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Well, I found a clue from the given documentation of `ui-router` the says

> You can assign a controller to your template. **Warning:** The controller will not be instantiated if template is not defined.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#controllers

But I tried to add `template` and still didn't work, then I saw that my parent route template didn't have `<div ui-view></div>` (I mistakenly removed it) so when I added it back it worked :), So, to instantiate our child's route controller, we must have `<div ui-view></div>` in our parent's route template.

Comment: +1 buddy.  I was playing around for 2-3 hours and didn't realize I just needed to add a ui-view to my parent view.  Makes total sense too....

Comment: Side note, I only have named view. I had a redirect state with a simple controller that changes state after some resolves finish. Had to add a 'views' key to target the named view, then the controller fired.

Comment: @makki : i have already have this <div ui-view></div> , do we still need to add again for my parent controller to

Comment: Interesting. I am using named views, and in my parent view, I do have UI-View where I am using my nested views name. Will that do the trick, or do I need to enclose the entire parent view inside an UI-view?

Answer (score 40):

Another reason the controller may not be called is if you have multiple views for a state and don't put the controller inside the views object. This is difficult to find because there is no error. It just doesn't get called.

This controller won't be called:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: function($scope){ $scope.someThings = "some stuff"; },
    views: {
        "view1": {                
            template: '<p>{{someThings}}</p>'
        },
        "": {
            template:
                '<p>Some other stuff</p>'
        }
    }
})
```

The controller must go inside the views object:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/',        
    views: {
        "view1": {                
            template: '<p>{{someThings}}</p>',
            controller: function($scope){ $scope.someThings = "some stuff"; },
        },
        "": {
            template:
                '<p>Some other stuff</p>'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I wish I'd found this 6 hours ago :/

Comment: this was my problem... it seams the controller needs to be defined per template and not per state. thanks @david004

Answer (score 4):

In the off event someone is changing a project to work with ui.router as opposed ngRoute, I had this issue because I forgot to change the ng-view directive to ui-view :Z