# Why does $timeout affect how $stateParams is resolved in a ui-bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

Following the [ui-router FAQ entry](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state), I recently implemented a generic AngularJS service that turns any ui-router state definition into a state definition that wraps a ui-bootstrap modal.

As a part of this, the `resolve` object needs to be pushed down from the state definition to the `$modal.open()` options.  The major problem with this is that the `$stateParams` that is injected into these resolve functions are those of the previous state.  After many hacky attempts at solving this, I found that simply wrapping the `$modal.open()` call in a `$timeout` block results in the desired behavior.

**In general, I'd like to understand *why* this works the way that it does, whether or not it's an acceptable solution, and if there are any caveats involved.**  In the past I've been able to resolve several Angular timing issues by simply wrapping a block of code in `$timeout`, and it makes me nervous since I'm really not sure why it works.  I'm guessing that a `$timeout` forces the block to run after the current digest cycle ends, but I'm not too confident about that.

I created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QhSyAz6P4DcBQawP036U?p=preview) that demonstrates this -- if you remove the `$timeout` and invoke the modal, the parameter will not resolve.

Note: As a caveat, I MUST be able to resolve `$stateParams` properly in the modal resolves -- I have many existing controllers and state definitions that I'd rather not have to go back and refactor.

Follow-up: I have created [ui-router issue 1649](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1649) to request a resolution to this issue -- also linked there is a [minimal Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9cWHYJLIUrj8yNiqnLXy?p=preview) that only uses `$injector.invoke` to demonstrate the issue with no modal at all.

Comment: Looks like you changed the plunker that you linked to in this question. It's typically a good idea to [freeze](http://embed.plnkr.co/oDjpFT/preview) your plunker

Comment: Thanks, fixed.  I thought I did that originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have not transitioned yet to the new state when secondparam is being resolved. The $timeout puts your code at the end of the queue, the state transition happens then executes your code with the expected state. You can tell by logging or alerting the current state in your resolve config:

```
secondparam: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {
    alert($state.$current.url); //here
    return $stateParams.secondparam;
}]
```

Unfortunately the documentation for onenter and onexit does not clearly tell when in the lifecycle they are invoked: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#onenter-and-onexit-callbacks. However [this post](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-ui-router.html) gives some indication:

> These callbacks give us the ability to trigger an action on a new view
>   or before we head out to another state.

I think you'd be better off using a controller and opening your modal there instead of the $timeout (where I believe your context will be window/global).

```
$stateProvider.state('demo.modal', {
  url: '/modal/:secondparam',
  template: 'showing modal',
  controller: function($scope, $modal, $state){
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      template: '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Remove the $timeout and this will not resolve: {{secondparam}}</div>',
      resolve: {
        secondparam: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {
          console.log($state.$current.url, $stateParams); //you are in the new state
          return $stateParams.secondparam; //'secondparam' IS resolved, even without $timeout
        }]
      },
      controller: function($scope, secondparam) {
        $scope.secondparam = secondparam;
      }
    });
    modalInstance.result.finally(function() {
      $state.go('^');
    });
  }
});
```

Note that I had to add `<div ui-view></div>` to the demo state to get the controller to instantiate ([ui-router nested route controller isn't being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866931/ui-router-nested-route-controller-isnt-being-called)).

```
$stateProvider.state('demo', {
  url: '/demo/:firstparam',
  template: '<button class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref=".modal({ secondparam: 2 })">Show Modal</button>' +
      '<button class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="demo.contacts">Show Contacts</button><div ui-view></div>'
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zdSkAsEyIef0tWxSTC5p?p=preview

Comment: Please see the note that I added to the question.  I need to be able to resolve `$stateParams` in the modal resolve.  Is the use of `$timeout` is "safe" here?

Comment: I wouldn't use $timeout, it's unnecessary complexity - I didn't update the comment from the plunkr, but `$stateParams` is resolving for me (to: `Object {firstparam: "1", secondparam: "2"}`)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot add modal-specific logic to the controller function, as I want to use the same controller whether or not the content is inside of a modal or not.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an unintended behavior, or something "by design" of `onEnter`.

The solution is to inject `$stateParams` into the `onEnter` handler - it would point to the params of the second state (as per [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider#methods_state)) of `onEnter`.

```
$stateProvider.state('demo.modal', {
  url: '/modal/:secondparam',
  onEnter: showModal,
  // ...
});

function showModal($state, $stateParams) {
   var secondparam = $stateParams.secondparam; // equals 2
   ...
   // BUT, the state has not yet transitioned
   var secondParamFromState = $state.params.secondparam; // is undefined

   ...
}
```

The `$timeout` allows the state to transition, and the the `resolve` of the `$modal` gets injected the current params, which would be for the second state.

EDIT: updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FILurv8TrXUit1MWjYrJ?p=preview)

Comment: Please see the note that I added to the question.  I need to be able to resolve `$stateParams` in the modal resolve.  Is the use of `$timeout` is "safe" here?

Comment: It's hacky, but probably harmless. I think the better way is how I suggested - I edited the question with your plunker updated - and without $timeout

Comment: Unfortunately my requirement is that the state `resolve` object can be used as the modal `resolve` object and resolve things the same way.  If there were a way to force `$stateParams` to always be injected as the object passed into `onEnter` that'd be great, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Here, it seems like when the $modal is invoked, `$stateParams` injected into the $modal's resolve reflects the current (not-yet-transitioned-from) state, and `$stateParams` injected into `onEnter` - that of next state. DRY is an important concept, but only to an extent. You can always create an anonymous wrapper around your real (and reusable) `resolve` fn or use the `$timeout` trick. Either way, I think both this and another answer address your question of "why", right?