# UI-Router Module Not loading because Controller not found

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've searched the [Ui-Router Controller Docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#controllers) and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866931/ui-router-nested-route-controller-isnt-being-called) here on stack overflow, along with other Google Searches. I'm trying to assign a controller to a state, but I get the the error:

```
Uncaught Typeerror: [$injector:modulerr]...controller cannot be found
```

I've borrowed a simpole [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpEPgq?editors=101) to show a similar outcome to what I get in my code.

If I remove **exampleCtrl** from my state definition all works fine:

```
...
.state('tab1', {
   name: 'tab1',
   url: '/tab1',
   template: '<div class="tab tab1"><p>Caerphilly</p></div>',
   controller: exampleCtrl
})
...
```

Is this a matter of order? or am I missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`controller: "exampleCtrl"` instead of `controller: exampleCtrl`

Comment: Wow that's a silly mistake. Sometimes we need a second set of eyes. Thank you.